# BT connectivity(connection / unpair) is not working properly

Tags: applications, bluetooth, bluetooth-audio, bluetooth-pairing

I am working on **Toradex apalis imx6q** with **Android Nougat**. When we try remove the paired device(bu clicking unpair), unpair was done properly. **But, still music playing on bluetooth headsets.**

**Steps::**

1.Go BT and connect your phone.

2.start play music.

3.go to BT(headset/phone) and unpair the device.

**Observation::**

still song/error is playing in the bluetooth headset.

Regards, 
VinothS

Comment: Is there a question? This site is for end users of Android, not bug reports for Android Open Source Project or bug reports for manufacturers of Android hardware/software systems.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Comment: The issues in bluetooth stack. I want to disconnect the headset after unpair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem in the bluetooth stack side. I identified and resolved this problem. The solutions of this problem is needs to disconnect after unpair the headset.